# Node server async call to backend service

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, axios, event-loop

I am new to Node and I am writing my very first node server. It should answer to a simple get request with a simple page after calling a backend rest service.

I am using express to manage the request and the axios package to make the backend request. The problem is that the server is blocking the event loop and I have problems understanding how to make the call to the backend asynchronous.

As of now the frontend server can only manage one request at a time!! I expected that if the backend service takes 10 seconds to answer everytime, the frontend server can answer two concurrent request in 10 seconds and not in 20 seconds.

**Where am I wrong?**

Here is an extract of the frontend node code:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

      //Making the call to the backend service. This should be asynchronous...
      axios.post(env.get("BACKEND_SERVICE"), 
      { "user": "some kind of input"})
        .then(function(response){

        //do somenthing with the data returned from the backend...

        res.render('homepage');
        })
    }
```

And here it is and extract of the backend node code:

```
app.post('/api/getTypes', jsonParser, function (req, res) {

      console.log("> API request for 'api/getTypes' SLEEP");
      var now = new Date().getTime();
      while(new Date().getTime() < now + 10000){ /* do nothing */ }
      console.log("> API request for 'api/getTypes' WAKE-UP");

      res.json({"types":"1"});
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your busy-wait ties up the backend server such that it can't even begin to process the second request.

I assume you're trying to simulate the process of getting the types taking a while. Odds are what you're going to be doing to get the types will be async and I/O-bound (reading files, querying a database, etc.). To simulate that, just use `setTimeout`:

```
app.post('/api/getTypes', jsonParser, function (req, res) {

  console.log("> API request for 'api/getTypes' SLEEP");
  setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("> API request for 'api/getTypes' WAKE-UP");
      res.json({"types":"1"});
  }, 10000);
});
```

That avoids hogging the backend server's only thread, leaving it free to start overlapping handling for the second (third, fourth, ...) request.

This is one of the key principles of Node: Don't do things synchronously if you an avoid it. :-) That's why the API is so async-oriented.

If you do find at some point that you have heavy CPU-burning crunching you need to do to process a request, you might spin it off as a child process of the server rather than doing it in the server process. Node is single-threaded by design, achieving very high throughput via an emphasis on asynchronous I/O. Which works great for most of what you need to do...until it doesn't. :-)

---

Re your comment:

> The backend process will be written in another technology other than node, it will call a DB and it could take a while. I wrote that simple node rest service to simulate that. What I would like to understand is how the frontend server will react if the backend takes time to process the requests.

There's a big difference between taking time to process the requests and tying up the only server thread busy-waiting (or doing massive CPU-heavy work). Your busy-wait models doing massive CPU-heavy work, but if getting the types is going to be external to Node, you won't be busy-waiting on it, you'll be queuing a callback for an asynchronus completion (waiting for I/O from a child process, or I/O from a socket connected to a third server process, or waiting on I/O from the DB, etc.). So the `setTimeout` example above is a better model for what you'll really be doing.

The busy-wait keeps the front-end from completing because it goes like this:

```
                               Backend
Time    Frontend                Queue                        Backend
−−−−    −−−−−−−−−−         −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−        −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
0 sec   Request #1  −−−−−−> Receive request #1   −−−−−> Pick up job for request #1
0 sec   Request #1  −−−−−−> Receive request #2
                                                        Busy wait 10 seconds
10 sec  Got #1 back <−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− Send response #1
                                                 −−−−−> Pick up job for request #2
                                                        Busy wait 10 seconds
20 sec  Got #2 back <−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− Send response #2
```

So even though the front-end isn't busy-waiting, it sees 20 seconds go by because the backend busy-waits (unable to do anything else) for 10 seconds for each request.

But that's not what your real setup will do, unless the other technology you're using is also single-threaded. (If it is, you may want to have more than one of them run in parallel.)

Comment: Yes, the code above is just to simulate the backend process of getting the types taking a while. The backend process will be written in another technology other than node, it will call a DB and it could take a while. I wrote that simple node rest service to simulate that.

What I would like to understand is how the frontend server will react if the backend takes time to process the requests.

Comment: @Roberto: I've added to the end of the answer. From your description, the backend Node server won't be stuck on heavy CPU work while getting the types. I've also explained why the front-end (which isn't busy-waiting) is affected by the busy-wait in the backend.